# Finding a matrix of an odd determinant

Tags: matrices, determinant

I am trying to find a square matrix of size $n$ consisting of zeros and ones whose determinant is an odd number. Any ideas?

Comment: Take any integer matrix with odd determinant, and replace all the even entries with zero, all the odd entries with one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All identity matrices have determinant $1$.

More generally, all *permutation* matrices have determinant $\pm1$, and remember that adding a multiple of any row to any other row does not change the determinant. This should already give you many, many examples.

Another example (not in the instances described above) of a zero-one matrix with odd determinant is a $2n×2n$ matrix with zeros on the diagonal and ones elswehere – this has determinant $1-2n$.

Finally, the most general way of constructing a zero-one matrix with odd determinant is to take any integral matrix with odd determinant and reduce modulo $2$ (odds to $1$, evens to $0$), since $\mathbb Z_2$ is a field.

Comment: True, I should have added that any other matrix other than the identity matrix and preferably one that looks like a random matrix of zeros and ones?

Comment: +1 More generally, any permutation matrix has determinant $\pm 1$.

Comment: @TravisWillse I edited that in already - how often do you see a question answered in a minute?

Comment: Rarely, though in this case the simplest answer is short.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a matrix $A$ such that $A^TA=I$ then

$$1=\det(I) = \det(A^TA) = \det(A)^2$$

Answer (score -1):

Also any diagonal matrix with odd elements on the diagonal, in fact:

$$\det(A)=a_{1,1}  \cdots a_{n,n}$$

Comment: Also any triangular matrix with odd elements on the diagonal

Comment: But the question asked for matrices of zeros and ones.

Comment: Put 1 as  elements on diagonal, 0 below it and random combination of 1 and 0 above it